# Lectura y Escritura archivo binario de 7 GBytes

Tags: archivo, delphi

Cómo puedo leer y escribir un archivo binario de más de 7 GBytes?

El assign(f,'xx' y el reset(f) funcionan pero cuando voy a iniciar el recorrido del archivo, la función eof(f) no opera adecuadamente, entiendo que es porque la estructura TFileRec tiene los campos BufPos y BufEnd definidos como cardinal y solo pueden representar hasta 4 GBytes.

Qué grupo de funciones puedo utilizar para realizar la operación descrita?

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSplitClick1(Sender: TObject);
Var
  F,G : File Of RecCustom;
begin
  System.Assign(F,'NameInputF');
  System.Reset(F);
  System.Assign(F,'NameOutputF');
  System.Reset(F);
  while Not System.Eof(F) Do Begin
    BlockRead(F,Arr,1);
    // Modifica record Arr
    BlockWrite(G,Arr,1);
  End;
  System.Close(F);
end;
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones `assign()`, `reset()` y similares datan de hace muchos años y, quizás por razones de compatibilidad, no han sido actualizados para soportar las características de los sistemas de archivos modernos, por ejemplo, archivos tan grandes (que antes simplemente eran impensables).

Delphi provee una serie de clases de las que puedes tirar para construir una solución moderna y orientada a objetos para procesar archivos de la manera que lo deseas. La más básica, sería utilizando `TFileStream`, por ejemplo, adaptando tu código, podría ser algo en la línea de:

```
var
  Origen, Destino: TFileStream;
  ARec: RecCustom;
  NumRegistros, I: Int64;
begin
  Origen := TFileStream.Create('Entrada.dat', fmOpenRead);
  try
    Destino := TFileStream.Create('Salida.dat', fmCreate);
    try
      NumRegistros := Origen.Size div SizeOf(ARec);
      for I := 1 to NumRegistros do
      begin
        Origen.ReadBuffer(ARec, SizeOf(ARec));
        ModificarRegistro(ARec);
        Destino.WriteBuffer(ARec, SizeOf(ARec));
      end;
    finally
      Destino.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Origen.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta

Comment: Un gusto, sin embargo veo que has hecho varias preguntas y no has marcado ninguna respuesta como aceptada. Hacerlo ayuda a la comunidad a identificar a primera vista las respuestas que han sido de ayuda para quien hizo originalmente la pregunta. Un saludo.